# Iterator Java to store object

Tags: java, iterator

I need to store objects using iterator but I found just the last element, what do you think ?

```
if (links.size()>0) {
    for (Iterator<Link> iterator = links.iterator();
        iterator.hasNext();) {
        Link link = (Link) iterator.next();
        item.setLink(link);
        objects.add(item);
    }
}
```

In `objects`, I pass to `item` and I found the last link, so what should I do? This idea will work `item.setLink( list of links);` or not?

Comment: An `Iterator` cannot add an object to the collection you're working with, at most it can remove the current element you're visiting.

Comment: Thank's but, what I should do ?

Comment: I don't know. I don't even understand what you're trying to accomplish here. We literally have no idea what's your current issue and why your design can or cannot support it.

Comment: Ok, I had links and I try to set all links into item, and add item to Objects, where's the problem ? or how I can do that ?

Comment: Can an `Item` handle several `Link`s? Can a `Link` be related to several `Item`s? Answer these questions, then you will answer yourself the design issue you may have (or may not have).

Comment: my friend this just a part of my code, for you it's setLink but for me it's storage into database using Realm, any way thank's for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve as the code has several problems:

- you're setting the link in the class object in each iteration which is why only the last element remains (this is assuming the .setLink() method doesn't do anything funky inside)
- if your objects collection (is it a collection?) is a Set and the item hashCode method computes its value based on the link value only your elements will be replaced

It's a guess only but perhaps this is what you're trying to do?

```
for (Link link : links) { // works only if your collection is properly typed
    MyClass item = new MyClass();
    item.setLink(link);
    objects.add(item);
}
```

A couple of other suggestions:

- use an enhanced for loop (as shown above)
- the if (links.size()>0) { line is redundant -- your loop will simply do nothing if the collection is empty